# (C++) What is the issue with my saveGame() function? When I call the function, nothing within it runs but there is no error?

Tags: c++, function, file, save, fstream

I have tried almost everything, yet I can't figure out why this function won't do anything when I call it. The function is called properly: `saveGame(hscore, selectedSaveSlot);` (`hscore` and `selectedSaveSlot` have been properly defined as `int`s as well). Additionally, this function is called within another function, within a `switch` statement. Does anyone have any ideas as to why it won't work?

**(i.e. When this function is called the `cout` doesn't say anything and no save file is created, the code simply skips over it and continues to run seamlessly).**

```
void saveGame(int highscore, int saveSlot) {        
ofstream saveFile1;
ofstream saveFile2;
ofstream saveFile3;
switch (saveSlot) {  
case '1':

    saveFile1.open("SaveFile1.txt", ios::out);



        saveFile1 << highscore;//writing highsore to a file

        saveFile1.close();
        cout << "Your game has been saved successfully!" << endl;
        delayScroll(10, 50);

        break;
case '2':
    saveFile2.open("SaveFile2.txt", ios::out);



        saveFile2 << highscore; //writing highsore to a file

        saveFile2.close();
        cout << "Your game has been saved successfully!" << endl;
        delayScroll(10, 50);

        break;
case '3':
    saveFile3.open("SaveFile3.txt", ios::out);



        saveFile3 << highscore; //writing highsore to a file

        saveFile3.close();
        cout << "Your game has been saved successfully!" << endl;
        delayScroll(10, 50);

        break;
    }
inMenu = true;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't specific enough, but hopefully someone can provide an answer or any suggestions. Any feedback is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Could it be that `saveSlot` is not in the range `'1' .. '3'`, or that it is in fact an `int` with values `1 .. 3`? In a `switch` statement, it always makes sense to have a `default:` label, even if it is only to tell you that none of the other labels applied, and that there might be an error. But I *guess* you actually meant `case 1:` etc. and not `case '1':`, etc.

Comment: What does your terminal say when the function is invoked? Try printing out some variables to debug(like saveSlot).
Also why are you using switch statements for this? You register them so that you dont have to change the code.

Comment: According to the answer from *taskinoor* I suggest you use a debugger. Then you would see immediatelly what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably calling `saveGame` with integer 1, 2, 3 etc. However,`'1'` and `1` are not same. The first one (with quotes around) is a character whose ASCII value is 49, the second one is integer one. Inside the switch you are using character `'1', '2', '3'`. They will match if you call `saveGame(highscore, 49)` or `saveGame(highscore, 50)` or `saveGame(highscore, 51)` respectively. But they won't match for `saveGame(highscore, 1)` or `saveGame(highscore, 2)` or `saveGame(highscore, 3)`.

In short, these are true:

```
'1' != 1
'2' != 2
'1' == 49
```

Change your cases to use actual integers.

Comment: Actually, whether `'1' == 49` is implementation dependent. There may be platforms that do not use ASCII.

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought it was 'int' but no! I ran the code the correct way and now the function works as intended! Also, thanks for the thoroughness of explaining that '1' has an ASCII value of 49! Another thing I learned today...